# Using a regex to extract a set of numbers and/or blank lines

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm constructing a regex using PCRE to process text to extract a set of numbers from a set of text lines (the lines are produced by parsing HTML with XPATH but the question doesn't depend on that). If the number required isn't present, I need to return a blank line.

I'm using a module in Drupal called Feeds Tamper that provides a limited set of options to modify the content -- including a Regex find and replace based on PCRE (not PCRE2). I have options to do a sequence of Regex Find and Replace and/or simple Find and Replace.

The input takes the format:

`Text A Location1 More text q=1,2)" Even more text
Text B
Text C Location1 More text q=3,4)" Even more text
Text D`

There can be any number of lines including and not including the digits I want to extract; the last line may or may not have a digit in it; I need to process all the lines and end up with one result per line and no extras. The results are then replaced with a capturing group.

My search Regex currently looks like

```
.*?Location1.*?q=(.*?),(.*?)".*?(\r|$)|.*?(\r|$)
```

and my replacement like

\1|

but (see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2tG0Uh/3)) this gives results such as

```
1||
||
3||
||
||
```

where the expected output is:

```
1|
|
3|
|
```

i.e there is an extra line at the end that doesn't correspond to an input line, and an extra pipe character at the end of each line.

If I use

```
.*?Location1.*?q=(.*?),(.*?)".*?\r|.*?\r
```

the last line is omitted so I get:

```
1|
|
3|
```

If I don't add a pipe | to end of the substitution I get the right number of lines with the expected content (digit or blank), but as soon as I add something at the end of the substitutionI get an extra line and the substituted characte ris doubled.

What do I need to change in my Regex and why?

Comment: It seems like DOM manipulation, there must be a solution without that complication. What language are you using? javascript? Or are you doing this at backend?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes -- neither. I'm using a module in Drupal called Feeds Tamper that provides pretty limited options including a Regex Find and Replace.

Comment: can you provide expected output?

Comment: @SergeyKhalitov OP has been edited to include it.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't replace by `\1` conditionally, doesn't Feeds Tamper have another method to just match the desired results instead of replacing what you don't want?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Unfortunately, no. I can do a Find Replace Regex or a simple Find Replace but the input is variable enough in content that a simple Find Replace won't work. However, I can do a sequence of Find Replace Regex.

Comment: Maybe replacing [`^.*?(?:q=(\d+[.]\d+)|$).*`](https://regex101.com/r/YVWdux/1/) by `\1`, then I'm not sure how adding the `|` pipe character

Comment: I'm strugglint to improve this question to adress the closure votes -- can anyone provide guidance on what is missing (unclear) or too broad? I think I'm asking about a specific Regex problem with a defined input and an expected output, using a specific dialect of Regex but I'm clearly missing something additional that's needed.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes, your suggestion just returns two blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
^(?:.*Location1.*?q=(\d+),(\d+))?.*$
```

First it matches start of line, optionally followed by the "required" `Location` and `q=` parts and captures the numbers. Finally it matches anything up to the end.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b7EdCU/1).

Comment: The explanation will help me debug other Regexes.